# Determining upper bound on truncation error

Tags: numerical-methods

Determine an upper bound on the truncation error resulting from estimating $\sin x$ by $T_5(x), x \in [-0.2,0.2]$

Workings:

Take $x = -0.2$

$f(x) = \sin (x)$

$\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + ...$

$= T_5(x) + R_5(x)$

$R_5(x) = f^{(6)} (\xi)(x-a)^6$

$|R_5(x)| \leq \max |f^{(6)}(\xi) |\frac{(0.2)^6}{6!}$

$f^{(6)} (x) = -\sin x$

$|R_5(x)| \leq 1 \frac{(0.2)^6}{6!} = 8.88 \times 10^{-9}$

Now I'm not sure what to do would I go on and take $x = -0.1$ until I get up to $x = 0.2$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in this case $a=0$ and $|x-a|=|x|<0.2\;\forall\;x\in[-0.2,0.2]$. So the bound you've calculated works for the whole interval.

Comment: Ok I see thanks.